# Disable button on click but cannot pass parameter to controller

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a button, which when clicked I want to disable.

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" style="float: right; position: relative; right: -18px;" />
```

The value "Save" needs to pass from the button to the controller:

```
 public ActionResult EditCall(ModelCallDetails call, string submit)
```

but, obviously when I put an OnClick event such as disable, the parameter is not pushing to the controller.

Is there anyway of actually passing the value to the controller, the form is still posting the model info.

Comment: Dont use disabled, Use on click and once when you get parameters , dont do anything in onclick and return false

Answer (score 1):

Use `onsubmit` event.

Example :

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">  
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" style="float: right; position: relative; right: -18px;" /> 
</form>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
    function submitForm(th) {   
        th.submit.disabled = true;  
        return true;
    }  
</script>
```

You can test in the below snippet that when the button becomes disable, the submit event isn't called anymore. I only changed `return true` to `return false` because I shouldn't post to stackoverflow. It's just to show you that the event isn't callable anymore after having its submit button setted to `disabled=true`.

```html
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">  
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" /> 
    </form>  

    <script type="text/javascript">  
        function submitForm(th) {   
            th.submit.disabled = true;
            console.log("passed");
            return false;
        }  
    </script>
```

Comment: This isn't stopping the user from clicking the button again though.

Comment: The submit button becomes disable and the form isn't posted again. Isn't it what you are looking for ?

Comment: unfortunately it posts the form several times if I continue clicking the button. @Sébastien S.

Comment: I added a snippet to my answer where you can see that the submit event isn't called anymore when the button is disabled.